# How to write a sql script that cursors through a table and inserts into a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, unpivot, lateral-join

I am new to sql server i have the following table structure that contains more than a thousand rows.
But for example purposes this is what it would look like

Table Import

```
+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Name |  Code   | SocksTotal | GlovesTotal| JeansTotal | ShirtsTotal| shoesTotal |
+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| OT   |   45612 |          2 |          1 |          0 |          1 |          4 | 
| OT   |    1234 |          0 |          1 |          0 |          0 |          0 | 
| US   |    45896|          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 | 
+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

and a second table called Items follows

```
+------+---------+
| ID   |  Item   | 
+------+---------+
| 1    |   socks |
| 2    |   Gloves|
| 3    |   Jeans |
| 4    |   Shirts|
| 5    |   shoes |
+------+---------+
```

from the above tables i need to write a script that would be inserted into a different table called ImportItems_Summary.
the expected output is

```
+------+---------+------------+------------+
| Id   |  Code   | Items_id   |Import_total|
+------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1    |   45612 |          1 |          2 |
| 2    |   45612 |          2 |          1 |
| 3    |   45612 |          4 |          1 |
| 4    |   45612 |          5 |          4 |
| 5    |   1234  |          2 |          1 |
+------+---------+------------+------------+
```

as you can see here that code 45612 now has 4 entries into the ImportItems_summary table where the items is not equal to 0 and the Items_id is linked to the Items table ID column.

How can i achieve the above output?.. I read up and saw a cursor might help but i am not sure how to implement this

Comment: Why do you want to use a `CURSOR` here? SQL is a set based language, so using a `CURSOR`, which is an iterative method, should be one of the last options, not the first.

Comment: @Larnu it doesnt have to be a cursor, i just dont know how to achieve it ,i thought a cursor would help

Comment: The initial data you have is denormalised. Are those the only items you have, or do you really have 100's of columns for all the different item names? If so, do these all follow the structure of `{ItemName}Total` for the column name? Is fixing the design of the original table an option? It should be heavily considered.

Comment: @Larnu no i cant make any changes to the Tables ,that's the format that it is set in, currently i only have 5 items at the moment,im not sure if their will be more items or not

Comment: That is a concern, as you could build a static solution, however, as *soon* as you add a new item it will not scale and item would **not** be considered. The alternative would be to use a dynamic SQL approach, however, this is not introductory and you (I suspect, and with respect) would be unable to support the solution. Fixing the design, however, removes that problem.

Comment: @Larnu,no offense taken, my logic could be wrong but i was thinking if we cursor through the Import table and split each of the items into a new row and store that into a temp table and then work with that information?

Comment: Unpivoting would be far more performant, which is what GMB shows you. Just be aware that (like I mention) as soon as you add another product it won't scale. A `CURSOR` won't fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `cross apply` to unpivot the columns of the unnormalized table to rows, then brings the items table with a `join`, and finally inserts in the target table:

```
insert into ImportItems_Summary (code, items_id, import_total)
select im.code, it.items_id, x.import_total
from import im
cross apply (values 
    ('socks',  sockstotal),
    ('gloves', glovestotal),
    ('jeans',  jeanstotal),
    ('shirts', shirtstotal),
    ('shoes',  shoestotal)
) x(item, import_total)
inner join items it on it.item = x.item
```